# CLR GC thread behavior: SafeFileHandle unexpectedly finalized

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, safefilehandle

We recently hit some issues that may be related to the GC behavior of CLR.

The problem I encountered is as follows:

We have a long running stress testing application written in C# that keeps opening file handles on a remote SMB file share (which is Azure Files Service), and uses those handles to perform file system operations like read/write, etc.

Typically we’ll keep those handle open for quite a long time, as we’ll use them repeatedly. But sometimes when we try to access some of those opened handles, we found that these handles were closed already. And from the trace logs captured by Process Monitor (one sample below):

fltmgr.sys!FltpPerformPreCallbacks+0x324

fltmgr.sys!FltpPassThroughInternal+0x8c

fltmgr.sys!FltpPassThrough+0x169

fltmgr.sys!FltpDispatch+0x9e

ntoskrnl.exeIopCloseFile+0x146

ntoskrnl.exeObpDecrementHandleCount+0x9a

ntoskrnl.exeNtClose+0x3d9

ntoskrnl.exeKiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13

ntdll.dll!ZwClose+0xa

KERNELBASE.dll!CloseHandle+0x17

mscorlib.ni.dll!mscorlib.ni.dll!+0x566038

clr.dll!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83

clr.dll!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a

clr.dll!DispatchCallSimple+0x60

clr.dll!SafeHandle::RunReleaseMethod+0x69

clr.dll!SafeHandle::Release+0x152

clr.dll!SafeHandle::Dispose+0x5a

clr.dll!SafeHandle::DisposeNative+0x9b

mscorlib.ni.dll!mscorlib.ni.dll!+0x48d9d1

mscorlib.ni.dll!mscorlib.ni.dll!+0x504b83

clr.dll!FastCallFinalizeWorker+0x6

clr.dll!FastCallFinalize+0x55

clr.dll!MethodTable::CallFinalizer+0xac

clr.dll!WKS::CallFinalizer+0x61

clr.dll!WKS::DoOneFinalization+0x92

clr.dll!WKS::FinalizeAllObjects+0x8f

clr.dll!WKS::FinalizeAllObjects_Wrapper+0x18

clr.dll!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x2d

clr.dll!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c

clr.dll!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x75

clr.dll!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInCorrectAD+0x15

clr.dll!Thread::DoADCallBack+0xff

clr.dll!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x1d822c

clr.dll!WKS::DoOneFinalization+0x145

clr.dll!WKS::FinalizeAllObjects+0x8f

clr.dll!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0xa1

clr.dll!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x2d

clr.dll!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c

clr.dll!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x75

clr.dll!WKS::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0xd7

clr.dll!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d

KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1a

ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d

It seems that the handles were closed in CLR GC Finalizer thread. However, our handles are opened in the following pattern which should not be GC’ed:

We use P/Invoke to open a file handle and obtain a SafeFileHandle and use that SafeFileHandle to construct a FileStream, and we’ll save the FileStream object in another object defined as follows:

```
public class ScteFileHandle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// local file handle
    /// </summary>
    [NonSerialized]
    public FileStream FileStreamHandle;

    /*
     * Some other fields
     */
```

}

P/Invoke we use:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
       string lpFileName,
       Win32FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
       Win32FileShare dwShareMode,
       IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
       Win32FileMode dwCreationDisposition,
       Win32FileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
       IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

SafeFileHandle fileHandle = Win32FileIO.CreateFile(fullFilePath, win32FileAccess, win32FileShare, IntPtr.Zero, win32FileMode, win32FileAttr, IntPtr.Zero);

FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileHandle, fileAccess, Constants.XSMBFileSectorSize);

One thing we’re sure of is that during the whole lifetime of our stress testing application, we definitely keep a reference to the ScteFileHandle object, so it will never be cleaned up by GC. However, we do have observed the SafeHandle referenced within the ScteFileHandle ‘s FileStream got finalized in CLR GC thread, as pasted in above trace log.

So I’m wondering what caused the SafeFileHandle to be GC’ed and if there’s any approach to avoid this ? I’m not familiar with the CLR GC behavior but from my perspective, the SafeFileHandle is not supposed to be GC’ed.

Any pointer or insight is greatly appreciated ! Please let me know if any other detail you need to diagnostic this issue : )

Comment: SafeFileHandle can be collected as any other object, it's not special in this regard, but it has a flag that specifies whether the object owns the handle it holds, and if not, it won't close the handle when the object is collected. It looks as though you're holding on to the handle though but can you please show your last method that is on the stack when it was collected?

Comment: "Having" a reference to an `ScteFileHandle` object doesn't protect it from GC. Having a reference that might be read in the future does. So if it's only a local variable, just having it in that variable (if you never access it again) won't save it. Or if it's in a field of your class, that's got a wider scope, but if provably nothing needs `this` again within that class, *it* can be collected even when one or more of its methods is still running. Famously, the GC is aggressive enough that it can collect objects even if their *constructor* is still running, if no other `this` access is required

Comment: The GC is super aggressive, which means that unless you ensure you're holding on to the *objects* holding the handle, *they* might be collected even though you're not yet done with the handle, and thus start cleaning up things.

Comment: A typical problem with handles and such on objects is that in a method you grab the handle out of the field and into a local variable, then start doing P/Invoke. If GC kicks in and see that you have no more use for the actual object it might put it into the freachable queue for the finalizer to finalize before collecting it, and if this too manages to execute during your method, that finalizer might close the handle. Sort of like sawing off the branch you're sitting on.

Comment: The GC is so aggressive that it can even clean up the object on which you called the method, simply because the `this` reference is just a reference like any other at that point.

Comment: One way to ensure this is to use `GC.KeepAlive(yourObject);` at the end of your method that does P/Invoke, which is a non-optimizable/inlinable call that does nothing, except that because it explicitly cannot be optimized out ensures the object lives to tell the tale up until past that method call.

Comment: But without seeing the code which was executing at the time it is all conjecture.

Comment: Thanks @LasseVågsætherKarlsen for replying. Sorry for not describing my problem clearly. In our app, each handle is opened in a separate thread and will be used in another thread later. And after each handle is created, the ScteFileHandle which has reference to that SafeFileHandle will be stored in a static Dictionary variable which is alive during the lifetime of our app. Since we should be able to retrieve those handles from the static Dictionary anytime we want during the lifetime of the app, from my pespective, those handle should never got GC'ed ?

Comment: Do you clone the SafeFileHandle or construct SafeFileHandle objects yourself? I ask because I seriously doubt there is a bug in the .NET runtime at this point regarding objects being collected with live references to them. As such I am inclined to believe that *you* believe you still have a valid reference to it but you don't, so it was collected. Again, there is nothing special in this regard with SafeFileHandle, it's an object like any other.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the SafeFileHandle is just obtained from P/Invoke like posted above:<br>SafeFileHandle fileHandle = Win32FileIO.CreateFile(fullFilePath, win32FileAccess, win32FileShare, IntPtr.Zero, win32FileMode, win32FileAttr, IntPtr.Zero);

Comment: Yes, but I meant, do you clone this object, or construct new ones based on it?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen No. Except for using the SafeFileHandle to construct FileStream, I've never cloned or constructed new ones based on it.